# Desktop Application Data Files Deployment Strategy

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, packaging

I’m building a cross-platform, open-source application in the .NET Core (desktop console) for static site generation. This application supports the extensibility mechanism via plugins (.NET dlls), includes (razor .cshtml pages), themes, templates, etc. Let’s call this all **Data Files** or **Library Files** (the size is relatively small 10-20 MBs but can grow). The application will be redistributed as .NET Core Tool (nuget.org) and MS App Center as an alternative option (simple download).

Now, the challenge. What would be the best way/strategy of redistributing Data Files? The options I considered:

- Include data files directly in the application (package). However, this would inflate the application size and also make it hard to deliver library updates as this would require delivery of the application update as well.
- Add the command in application to download the library (e.g. –install-library). This command can simply download the files from the known url and add them into the *%APP_DATA%* folder or other location. The problem with this approach is hard to manage the files when updating the library as the user may change, move, add files to this location, and updating the library can overwrite the files unless some more complicated mechanism is developed to track changes.
- Download the library as zip file and keep it as zip. In this case, user is unlikely to change the content and it will be easy to deliver a new update – just overwriting the .zip file. The only disadvantage is it would be a slight performance hit as the library items need to be extracted on-demand from .zip, but only a few items needed at once and using [System.IO.Packaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) or other tools, it is possible to just extract what is needed.
- Let the user manually download and unzip data files

The question I have is there known frameworks, strategies, services to deliver this type of data files?

Are there any security concerns getting the files from the url. Sure, it will be HTTPS connection and I was also thinking to sign zip with a digital signature and validate it in the app when extracting. This can be done with [PackageDigitalSignatureManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.packaging.packagedigitalsignaturemanager?view=netcore-3.1) API, but although it is supported in .NET Core, it seems to only work in Windows as this is a part of WPF’s Windows Base.

Any hints or points would be greatly appreciated.